# How to create a urls.py for custom user profiles on Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to make custom user profile urls, so when a user visits their profile page, they would visit the url: accounts/(whatever the user's name is). After reading the django book, I know that I can capture arguments using accounts/d to capture digits, or accounts/[A-Za-z] for characters. What if I want to capture both digits and characters, since a username can have both?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the digits to your regex... `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Or just use `\w`.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

This regex is pretty standard for capturing a slug in django: 
`^accounts/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$`

Alphanumeric plus `-`: my-slug, my-s1ug, etc.